# How to deploy Windows Claims across forests with "Transform Claim policy"?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012, claims-based-identity

## Introduction

I have seen that Windows Server 2012 allows to filter or transform incoming and outgoing claims that traverse a forest trust. My goal is to achieve such a transformation or filter.

## Architecture

I have 2 domains (DomainA and DomainB) that each contain a Windows Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller (DCA and DCB) and a Windows 8.1 Client (ClientA and ClientB).

DomainA belongs to forest A and DomainB belongs to forest B.

These forests:

- are connected by one bidirectional trust,
- have domain set to Domain Functional Level "Windows Server 2012".

On each DC and clients, claims are enabled through Group Policy.

## Test of the architecture

Firstly, I want to ensure that claims are functional. To do this, I created a claim "country" with PowerShell on my DCA (according to [claim specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj552963)).

```
New-ADClaimType `
-AppliesToClasses:@('user') `
-Description:"User country" `
-DisplayName:"Country" `
-ID:"ad://ext/Country:mycompany" `
-IsSingleValued:$true `
-Server:"DomainA.com" `
-SourceAttribute:Country-Name
```

Then I log on my ClientA with a non-admin account (John) and I check his Claims.

```
PS C:\Users\John> whoami /claims

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

Claim Name       Claim ID                                 Flags Type   Values
================ ======================================== ===== ====== ======
"country"        ad://ext/Country:mycompany                     String "US"
```

Everything is ok. Cool !

I have done the same on DCB and I log on my ClientB with a non-admin account (Alex) and I check her Claims.

```
PS C:\Users\Alex> whoami /claims

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

Claim Name       Claim ID                                 Flags Type   Values
================ ======================================== ===== ====== ======
"country"        ad://ext/Country:mycompany                     String "EN"
```

Ok, I gather that the claims are functional on my two forests. The next step is to allow claims of John in the forest B.

## Setting Claim transformation

As my claim "Country" has the same name in the forest A and B, I do not need to perform a transformation. I just have to allow any claims from Forest A to Forest B (according to [this msdn example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831742.aspx)).

So, I apply these command lines on DCA:

```
New-ADClaimTransformPolicy `
-Description "Claims transformation policy to allow all claims" `
-Name "AllowAllClaims" `
-AllowAll `

Set-ADClaimtransformlink "DomainA.com" `
-Policy AllowAllClaims `
-Trustrole Trusted `

Set-ADClaimtransformlink "DomainA.com" `
-Policy AllowAllClaims `
-Trustrole Trusting `
```

I do the same on DCB:

```
New-ADClaimTransformPolicy `
-Description "Claims transformation policy to allow all claims" `
-Name "AllowAllClaims" `
-AllowAll `

Set-ADClaimtransformlink "DomainB.com" `
-Policy AllowAllClaims `
-Trustrole Trusted `

Set-ADClaimtransformlink "DomainB.com" `
-Policy AllowAllClaims `
-Trustrole Trusting `
```

Everything is ready, it remains only to test. I connect John (from forest A) on ClientB (on forest B). Connection is ok (thanks to bidirectional trust between both forest). Then I check his Claims.

```
PS C:\Users\John> whoami /claims

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.
```

It appears that transformation policy did not work... :(.

## Trying other values

### My claim transformation rule may be wrong...

... so I have done the same exercise with the following rules:

#### Deny all except country

```
New-ADClaimTransformPolicy `
-Name "DenyAllExceptCountry" `
-DenyAllExcept ad://ext/Country:mycompany
```

It did not work.

#### Allow all with the [transformation rules language](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848274.aspx)

```
New-ADClaimTransformPolicy `
-Name "CountryPolicy" `
-Rule 'C1:[Type=="ad://ext/Country:mycompany", Value=="US", ValueType=="string"] =>issue(Type="ad://ext/Country:mycompany", Value="US", ValueType="string");'
```

It did not work.

### My claim name may be wrong...

... so I created Claims from GUI (Active Directory Administrative Center, Dynamic Access Control).

I obtain this claim on my ClientA (forest A):

```
PS C:\Users\John> whoami /claims

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

Claim Name       Claim ID                                 Flags Type   Values
================ ======================================== ===== ====== ======
"country"        ad://ext/country:88d143124c753e5b              String "US"
```

And I obtain this claim on my ClientB (forest B):

```
PS C:\Users\Alex> whoami /claims

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

Claim Name       Claim ID                                 Flags Type   Values
================ ======================================== ===== ====== ======
"country"        ad://ext/country:65e654230a985c3b              String "EN"
```

#### Allow All rule

I apply *-AllowAll* rule again on both DC. It did not work.

#### Allow all with the [transformation rules language](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848274.aspx)

```
New-ADClaimTransformPolicy `
-Name "CountryPolicy" `
-Rule 'C1:[Type=="ad://ext/country:88d143124c753e5b", Value=="US", ValueType=="string"] =>issue(Type="ad://ext/country:65e654230a985c3b", Value="US", ValueType="string");'
```

It did not work.

## Debugging

### Active Directory schema

I tried to have a look at Active Directory schema, to make sure that the rules are defined. Rule transformations are defined in:

> CN=ms-DS-Claims-Transformation-Policies,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=DomainA,DC=com

I can see my *AllowAllClaims* policy which contains a *msDS-TransformationRules* attribute that seems ok. I also checked *ADClaimtransformlink* that seems ok too.

### Windows Event Logs

When I try to connect John (from forest A) on ClientB (forest B), no interesting event occurs. I have some *Audit Success*, no error and no message about claims.

### WinDBG

I tried to debug Kernel by putting a breakpoint on nt!*tranform* functions. Windbg **never** breaks on these functions !

## Questions

Who managed to run this new feature? Could you explain how you have done it (step-by-step)? What is wrong in my approach?